# Connecting to SQL Server with Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: sql-server, database, netbeans, jdbc, connection

I'm attempting to connect to SQLServer 2008 with the database connection wizard in netbeans. I already downloaded the jdbc and linked it to the .jar file, but it still won't connect. My fields seem to contain the right information.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The obvious questions are: Is there a driver for 2008 as the screen shot shows 2005? Also is SQL Server running as a named instance?

Comment: It's the sql jdbc for 2008 (version 3.0). Don't know why it's showing 2005. I resolved the problem by going into the SQL server configuration manager and adding port 1433 into the All IP Addresses section. Weird that I still needed to do that when the default port is usually 1433 for sqlserver. Thanks anyways.